# API response error: Can not deserialize instance

Tags: php, json

I am implementing recurrent payment with Pagseguro and in my request the body params is json:

```
{
  "plan":"*************",
  "sender":
  {
    "name":"Yuri Max Rodrigues Stolai",
    "email":"asd@gmail.com",
    "hash":"*************",
    "phone":{
      "areaCode":"99",
      "number":"999999999"
    },
    "address":{
      "street":"Street",
      "number":"100",
      "complement":"House",
      "district":"District",
      "city":"City",
      "state":"ST",
      "country":"BRA",
      "postalCode":"99999000"
    },
    "documents":{
      "type":"cpf",
      "value":"11045312673"
    }
  },
  "paymentMethod":
    {
      "type":"CREDITCARD",
      "creditCard":{
        "token":"*************",
        "holder":{
          "name":"Yuri Stolai",
          "birthDate":"01/07/1992"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

The return of request is:

> Can not deserialize instance of java.util.List out of START_OBJECT
>   token  at [Source:
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@4c4cc8ea; line: 22,
>   column: 6] (through reference chain:
>   br.com.uol.ps.api.resources.preapproval.params.jaxb.DirectPreApprovalParamJAXB["sender"]->br.com.uol.ps.api.resources.preapproval.params.jaxb.PreApprovalSenderParamJAXB["documents"])

Where is the problem?

Comment: I think the API is expecting the parameters to be a JSON array, not a single object.

Comment: Or maybe one of the elements is supposed to be an array. Do you have a link to the API documentation?

Comment: The documentation link: https://dev.pagseguro.uol.com.br/reference#ades%C3%A3o-ao-plano

Answer (score 1):

The `documents` property should be an array of objects, not a single object.

```
    "documents":[{
      "type":"cpf",
      "value":"11045312673"
    }]
```

Comment: i try and the return is:
{"error":true,"errors":{"17069":"Phone is mandatory.","17065":"Documents required.","61007":"document type is required."}}

Comment: I was looking at a different operation and assuming they were similar, but `Adesão ao plano` doesn't seem to require an array here.

Comment: Now I'm not sure why you're getting the original error.

Answer (score 0):

I cant't resolve this problem, but i found other way using one library based on the documentation API.

Answer (score 0):

documents need by array because you can send more then one documents; Example in  BRA have CPF and RG documents.
"documents":[
{
"type":"cpf",
"value":"11045312673"
},
{
"type":"rg",
"value" "32131231"
}
]